# Design Question, Thoughts on Path Finding for a Galaxy Map

Tags: c#, unity, path-finding

I am thinking through solutions for a galaxy map.  We have different solar systems that need to be connected.  I do think a-star (A*) is possibly a good solution but was curious if it was really the only solution.  The galaxy map should remain static for the entire game.  I've also included an image similar to how the galaxy map would be setup.

[image]

Comment: A* sounds like a perfect fit. What do you have against it?

Comment: If you need really fast pathfinding and your image is representative of the size of the final graph, then Floyd–Warshall would be a good alternative.

Comment: Your graph is tiny and with few branches (low edge count compared to vertex count). A* fits great, even though it works even better when you have many more edges than you do. In the end, though - does the pathfinding actually pose a performance problem? You could definitely find a good heuristic to make finding the best path a breeze. Also, you should easily be able to subdivide the graph to speed up the searching - this could be very fast since you've got a lot of leaves and low edge-to-vertex ratio, and your graph is nicely subdivisible in 2D.

Comment: @Christian: ...Why do you think Floyd-Warshall would be better than A\*?  It's `O(V^3)`, while A\* is `O(E + V log V)`.  Floyd-Warshall is typically only used when you have negative-edges, which A\* can't always handle correctly.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It's O(V^3) *once*. Since the graph doesn't change throughout the game, all further lookups are practically constant time (you obviously need one memory lookup for every edge along the shortest path so technically it's O(E) but well). The downside is the matrix of size V^2 you need to keep in memory which is only practical for small graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all.  I have nothing against A*, just was curious what kind of feedback I would get.